# Interpretation and meaning of "a@0==0" in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I cannot understand the meaning of this condition "`((a+0!=0) or (a@0==0))`" in the code bellow.
This code test if the input year is a leap year.

```
a = eval(input('Enter a year :')) 

if (a%4==0) and ((a+0!=0) or (a@0==0)): 
  print(a,"is a leap year") 
else: 
  print(a,"is not a leap year")
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What input does this script expect - what's the type of `a`? The `@` operator is not supported by Python's builtin types.

Comment: "a" is an integer value.

Comment: Then the operation `a @ 0` is an error.

Comment: But the code gives always the correct value.

another method I found :
if (a%4==0) and ((a%100!=0) or (a%400==0)): 
  print(a,"is a leap year") 
else: 
  print(a,"is not a leap year")

Comment: The error is only triggered when `a @ 0` is *evaluated*. In a condition `i and (j or k)`, `k` is only evaluated when `i` is True and `j` is False. In your case, that only happens when a is `0`; you will not see an error otherwise, as the broken condition is not evaluated.

Comment: Where did you get the initial code from? Why are you trying to use it? Do you know how boolean operators `or` and `and` work in Python?

Comment: I am new in python, i get it from this web site (https://python.developpez.com/cours/apprendre-python3/?page=page_22). I am training to program with python for Machine learning, yes I know how condition operators work but it is the first time I saw a condition like that, so i did not understand the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.5+, it is called, `__matmul__` which can be overloaded by user then it can mean anything you want.

Comment: How would `eval(input(...))` reliably provide a type from `numpy`?